# jQuery uncaught TypeError, works on every page but one?

Tags: jquery, magento, typeerror

I have a magento installation that uses jQuery and the jQuery Cookie files,

On my product pages the .cookie methods dont work I get the following...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie' limesharp.js:172
(anonymous function) limesharp.js:172
f.Callbacks.o jquery.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

Every page it works fine except the product page.

The .cookie.js file is present if i view source

Page can be found here http://mona.limebuild.net/furniture/blue-moon-bed.html

Cookie related code looks like this;

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//loads more jquery

if (jQuery.cookie("bannerTop") == 1) {
    jQuery('.cookie-banner').css('display','none');
    jQuery('.page').css('margin-top',0);
    jQuery('.overlay').css('display','none');
}
jQuery(window).click(function(){
    jQuery.cookie("bannerTop", 1, { expires: 30 });
    jQuery('.cookie-banner').fadeOut();
    jQuery('.page').css('margin-top',0);
    jQuery('.overlay').css('display','none');
});
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see one issue:

on your product paghe you are loading jquery twice, you load it before the cookie plugin, and also later on:

```
colorselectorplus/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

this seems to only happen on the product page